# How to customize Seahorse plugin behavior in Nautilus?

Tags: gnome, encryption, nautilus, gnupg, pgp

I use Fedora 14. The seahorse-plugins package adds a nifty context menu option in Nautilus that allows you to encrypt/decrypt files easily with your GPG key. But is it possible to customize its behavior? Could I make it to...

- Delete the original automatically after encryption?
- Make it use ASCII armor instead of raw binary?
- When encrypting a whole folder...

  - Make it use the zip (or tgz or whatever) format always instead of asking every time? As it is, I'm left with CompanySources, CompanySources.zip *and* CompanySources.zip.pgp!
  - Delete the intermediate zip file?
- Make it create encrypted files with the gpg extension instead of pgp?
- Not store my passphrase in session memory? (Ask me at every decryption operation.)